# Adding days to a ISO 8601 format date in Python

Tags: python, date-formatting

I need to add +3 hours to a date in iso 8601 format in python, for example "2022-09-21T22:31:59Z" due to time difference. In this time information that is returned to me from the API, I only need Y/M/D information, but due to the +3 hour difference, the day information needs to go one step further in the date information, as will be experienced in the date I conveyed in the example. How can I overcome this problem? I think the format of the date format is ISO 8601 but can you correct me if I am wrong?

ex. api response;

```
"createdDateTime": "2022-09-21T22:31:59Z"
```

what i need;

```
"createdDateTime": "2022-09-21T22:31:59Z" to "2022-09-22T01:31:59Z"
```

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. What you posted is a string, not even a JSON object. Is that the *actual* response? In any case you'll have to parse this string value into a `datetime`

Comment: Why do you want to add *3* hours? Is the *real* problem how to convert the date to a different timezone? The *correct* value in that case would be `2022-09-21T22:31:59+03:00`

Comment: Since the api I use is an external API, I do not interfere with the recorded time format. Therefore, I need to edit the format in the response I received. Since there is a +3 time difference, I need to add. In date format, I only need Y/M/D information, but when I add +3 hours, I am having problems because in some cases it will move forward in a day.

Comment: Do something like `parsed_date = datetime.strptime("2022-09-21T22:31:59Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")` and then `parsed_date += timedelta(hours=3)`. If you need to bring the value back to the same format use the previous conversion. `parsed_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")`

Comment: I repeat, dates are binary values, they have no format. There's no `Y/M/D` information and *no recorded time format*. `Z` represents UTC, ie `+00:00`. Times in different timezones have the actual offset instead of Z. If you don't like the value returned by adding 3 hours though, what *do* you want? Adding 3 hours to 10 PM *does* produce 1 AM in the next day.

Comment: In any case, if you had an actual JSON object you could parse it with `data=json.loads('{"createdDateTime": "2022-09-21T22:31:59+00:00"}')` and get the time string from there with `isostr=data['createdDateTime']`. `datetime.fromisoformat` can parse the ISO8601 but doesn't handle `Z`. You'll have to replace it with `+00:00`. `isostr=data['createdDateTime'].replace('Z','+00:00')`. Once you have that, `datetime.fromisoformat(isostr)` will get you the date. If you only want the date part, `.date()` returns a `date` value, ie `datetime.fromisoformat(isostr).date()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code it will definitely work:

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta

parsed_date=datetime.strptime("2022-09-21T22:31:59Z", "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ")

Updated_date = parsed_date+ timedelta(hours=3)

print(Updated_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a proper JSON string you can parse it with `json`, extract the string value, parse that with `datetime.fromisoformat` into a `datetime` value and then get the `date` from it :

```
import json
from datetime import datetime
data=json.loads('{"createdDateTime": "2022-09-21T22:31:59+00:00"}')
isostr=data['createdDateTime'].replace('Z','+00:00')
fulldate=datetime.fromisoformat(isostr)
fulldate.date()
-----
datetime.date(2022, 9, 21)
```

The replacement is necessary because `fromisoformat` doesn't understand `Z`

Adding 3 hours to `fulldate` will return 1 AM in the next day:

```
fulldate + timedelta(hours=3)
------
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 22, 1, 31, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

`fulldate` is in UTC. It can be converted to another timezone offset using `astimezone`

```
fulldate.astimezone(tz=timezone(timedelta(hours=3)))
---
datetime.datetime(2022, 9, 22, 1, 31, 59, tzinfo=datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=10800)))
```

Or in a more readable form:

```
fulldate.astimezone(tz=timezone(timedelta(hours=3))).isoformat()
---------------------------
'2022-09-22T01:31:59+03:00'
```

This is 1AM in the next day but *with a +3:00 offset*. This is still the same time as 22PM at UTC.

It's also possible to just replace the UTC offset with another one, without changing the time values, using `replace`:

```
fulldate.replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=3))).isoformat()
----------------------------
'2022-09-21T22:31:59+03:00'
```

That's the original time with a different offset. That's no longer the same time as `2022-09-21T22:31:59Z`

Comment: Juan's solution is perfectly worked thank u for helping Panagiotis!

Comment: Check again. I added all the options that show the difference between adding 3 hours and changing offsets. Adding 3 hours produces a different time entirely. If you tried to meet someone you'd be 3 hours late. Changing the offset returns the same time instant in a different timezone. The strings may be different but both values would refer to the same time

Comment: i have tested, working well